# Why COO matrices do not use a map (or any binary tree structure) to storage its information?

Tags: c++, data-structures, sparse-matrix

I was trying to learn what is a COO Matrix (Coordinate format matrix) and asking for some kind of ‘advice’ for a possible C++ implementation. I want to make an implementation of a COO Matrix with four basic operations (multiplication by constant, addition, subtraction and matrix product) plus accessing to an element by row and column index. I noticed that almost all of the implementations storage data with three equal-length arrays (or vectors): one for the row coordinates, other for the column coordinates and other for the data or values.

So, for a C++ class implementation I should have three `vectors`, possibly two `vector<size_t>` for the coordinates and one `vector<T>` (T is the template parameter) for the data.

My question is: Why it is done this way? Wouldn't be better (i. e. with a better overall time and memory efficiency for each of the operations) if I use some binary-tree data structure, like a `map`? I thought about using a `map<size_t, T>`, where the key value is the coordinate, mapped in one variable with something like `row*N+column` (N is the width of the matrix).

So if `n` is the total number of the non zero coordinates, then for accessing any value by index `(i, j)` of the Matrix that would take me `O(n)` with the three vector implementation (because I would have to iterate at most through all the row and column vector); while with my implementation would take only `O(log n)`.

Of course that I could also use an `unordered_map` to access in `O(1)` time <del>but that would be a waste of memory, while the idea of making a sparse matrix is to save memory</del> without a significant extra memory consumption. Has my proposal any huge flaw that I'm not seeing?

P.S. I asked for C++ because is the language I'm currently using but I think it's easy to generalize the question for almost all languages.

Comment: P. S. #2, if the question does not fit on this site, please move to a site where it would fit

Comment: What is your criterion for "better"?

Comment: P. S. #3: Migration of posts is harder than you may think. In the early days too many posts were migrated to sites that were also poorly suited, so walls went up.

Comment: @Peter I want to implement the four basic operations plus accesing by index. ‘Better’ means a better overall performance in **time** and **memory** usage for each operation

Comment: If you have to trade memory for time or vice-versa, which is preferred?

Comment: @user4581301 I think it depends. But I'm surprised that I didn't see any implementation like the one I thought. So maybe there's a big disadvantage that still I'm not realizing

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer this, but one thing you can do in the meantime is write up what you have in mind and throw it and the traditional implementation at [Quick Bench](https://quick-bench.com/). It may point out a clear winner. Remember that sometimes the extra smarts needed to get a more favourable time complexity cost too much for the general case. I've seen some O(n)s beat out O(log n)s long after I thought the log n would have dominated because the simplicity of the n-algorithm had better predictability of access.

Comment: Why would an unordered map be less memory efficient than an ordered map? Usually the opposite is the case as ordered maps (binary trees) have significant overhead for each (allocated) node and the pointers that need to be stored with them.

Comment: Also, could it be that the vectors use sorted order? If so, they probably effectively implement maps more efficiently, which is reasonable here since you don't need to deal with updates.

Comment: Binary search in a sorted vector is going to be noticeably faster and use much less memory than `std::map`. But insertion is more complicated (though for small-ish sizes, I still expect `vector` to win, despite nominal `O(n)` complexity). Perhaps those implementations optimize for speed of access over speed of modification.

Comment: @Luatic  Vectors don't "use sorted order".   They manage a contiguous dynamically allocated array, without any sorting.

Comment: @Luatic But wasn't  `unordered map` implemented with a hash table? doesn't a hash table consume more memory than a binary tree?

Comment: @tac what makes you think that a hash table consumes more memory than a binary tree? The hash table is dynamic here, it will usually be larger than its contents by a constant factor (say, 2 or less). It's not an array.

Comment: You could use your own storage, but if it differs significanlly don't call it COO.  Formats like this were developed years ago (1980, 90s), most likely in FORTRAN, for linear algebra jobs (e.g. Finite Element). Based on MATLAB and python experience, COO is primarily an input format.  CSR (or CSC) is used more for calculation purposes, especially matrix multiplication.

Comment: I'm wondering if [std::valarray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) would be useful to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the operations and make a (theoretical) analysis.

*Multiplication by a constant* can be done in linear time in the number of entries with any reasonable sparse map data structure. With the `vector`-based structure, you simply have to loop over the "data" vector and multiply each value with the constant. *You can't beat that.* It's optimal both asymptotically and in terms of cache locality. Storing the data "out of band" (e.g. not in a struct together with row and column) here pays off.

With something like a sorted map or a map of maps even, this will still be linear time, but with more overhead / worse constant factors: maps, typically implemented using balanced binary trees in C++, have much more overhead than vectors (a vector will in the worst case be twice as large as its contents; a binary tree needs to store left and right pointers for each node, meaning you need at least thrice the memory, and this isn't counting allocator accounting overhead etc.), and the linked structure is much worse for cache locality.

*Addition* effectively requires a "merge" of the matrices with the following rules:

- If only one of the matrices has an entry, keep it.
- If both matrices have an entry, add the two.

Assuming the rows and columns are sorted lexicographically, this is effectively just a linear time *sorted merge*; again you can't be better than this. Cache locality is also good: All six vectors (col, row, data of both matrices) are traversed sequentially.

*Subtraction* is analogeous to addition.

*Accessing an element by row and column index* is simply a binary search (again assuming lexicographic order). This is O(log n); it is not optimal - a hash map would beat this in the average case, by providing O(1) - but it is better than using sorted maps, which would be O(log n), but with a higher constant factor; again cache locality for the vectors is better: The last few steps of the binary search will be accessing values pretty close in memory.
(Side note: The cache locality issue of C++'s maps could to some extent be addressed by using B-Tree based maps instead, but I've only seen Red-Black-Trees in C++ so far.)

*Sparse matrix multiplication* of two sparse matrices A and B is trickier. Each entry in the new matrix will be the dot product of the corresponding row in A and the corresponding column in B. So, you get a product for every row of A times every column of B.

Due to the lexicographic order, you can iterate over the rows of A pretty conveniently (each row is just a range in your vectors where all entries have the same row value).

For B, you want the columns. This is somewhat awkward; you'll probably want to transpose the matrix by swapping rows and columns, and then sorting lexicographically again (note that all swaps need to be applied to all three vectors). This is O(n log n), but will likely be dwarfed by the cost of the matrix multiplication (excepting extreme cases like only a populated diagonal or similar). It also helps improve the cache locality when accessing elements in the same column, since they are now next in memory. [Transposing (non-sparse) matrices before multiplication can result in significant performance gains.](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Elstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf)

Now you loop over each row of A and each "column" (now row after the transposition) of B, looping over both matrices sequentially.

For each row of A, you have a couple of column values. You do a sorted merge of these with the "column" of B, with the rule that if there's only one value, you ignore it, and if there are two where column = row, you multiply them and add them to the sum. This gives you lexicographically sorted new entries for the resulting product matrix; you just need to stuff them in a vector.

Your sorted maps won't be any better w.r.t. to logarithmic factors. Again you just have higher overhead vs. vectors, and worse cache locality.

**TL;DR:** Sorted maps have higher overhead (both more complex logic and more memory usage). They suffer from worse cache locality.

Since you don't have an operation where you need to insert new entries into or remove entries from large sparse matrices (which would be a linear time operation in vectors, and logarithmic time in maps), they aren't useful yet.

---

An unsorted map (hash map) would likely have lower overhead than the sorted map and could provide O(1) expected time access to entries. However it still probably isn't more suitable than the vectors:

- *Multiplication by a constant* won't be and can't be any faster. It may even be slower as iterating over a hash map may involve skipping "deleted" / "empty" entries.
- *Addition* likely won't be faster either. You can still do the sorted merge in linear time (iterate over one matrix, look the (row, col) coords up in the other matrix), but you will be wildly jumping around in the memory of the other matrix.
- *Matrix multiplication* pretty much has the same issue of wildly jumping around in the memory of one matrix, but at least you get rid of the logarithmic factor here.

Asymptotically, unordered maps are as good or even better than vectors of coords and data. Overhead-wise, I'd expect much less overhead than from sorted maps, both memory and runtime-wise.

Practically you'll have to test whether they can beat the `vector`-representation. Especially for the matrix multiplication it's hard to tell; it also depends much on the sparse matrices you're dealing with.